# ArcPy CopyFeatures_management() naming error

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, file-geodatabase

I'm trying to reproject and copy some shapefile featureclasses to a file geodatabases and I'm having problems with the names imported. The code Im using is

```
# -*- coding: iso-8859-1 -*-
# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-

fcItem = "gsd_ap.shp"
outWorkspace = "database.gdb"
outCS = "1330"
fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses() for fcItem in fcList:
    outFC = os.path.join(outWorkspace, fcItem.strip(".shp"))
    arcpy.Project_management(fcItem, outFC, outCS)
```

Unfortunately the outFC name in the file geodatabase becomes gsd_a, the last letter disappears. The same happens if the last letter is a "s". There are more letter combinations that don't work as well.

Why does this happens? CopyFeatures_management() does exactly the same.

Doing the above inside ArcGIS Desktop using toolbox, this does not happen, only when I try a standalone script.

Comment: Are you running the stand alone script directly from the command line (ie `python myscript.py`) or through the interpreter or other console  (IDLE, IPython, etc.)?

Comment: If you print outFC does the filename include the issue you described?  Is the path sent to Project_management correct?

Comment: In the code you posted, the fcItem variable is getting overwritten with each iteration of the loop (so by the time it's passed to Project, it may not be gsd_ap.shp anymore). Also make sure your workspace is set to where your Shapefiles are stored (arcpy.env.workspace = '/path/to/shapefiles'), or else ListFeatureClasses won't list the right data.

Comment: @roms - Workspace is set correctly, I just forgot to include that.

Comment: @MatthewSnape - Yes it does. I found the error by adding the line 
     print fcItem + " " + outFC 
and get the error when creating the outFC variable. In the above example, fcItem = "gsd_ap.shp" but fcItem.strip(".shp") = "gsd_a"

Comment: @EvilGenius - from Idle...

Comment: This is a python issue, apparently strip removes all instances of the characters listed.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853914/strange-behaviour-of-python-strip-function

Comment: @Matthew Snape - this was the right way to go! By changing fcItem.strip(".shp") above to fcItem[:2] that specific problem were solved.

I think this is a significant thing to mention as the ESRI documentation allways seem to use fcItem.strip(".shp").

Comment: Just a small nitpick, strip() doesn't remove all instances of the characters, it removes all instances of the characters working from each end of the string. E.g. 'shapefile.shp'.strip('.shp') results in 'apefile' (note the 'p').

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are referring to EPSG projection code 1330 then a spatial reference should be defined in the following manner:

```
sr = arcpy.SpatialReference(1330)
```

Then change the reference from the string outCS to the spatial reference

```
arcpy.Project_management(fcItem, outFC, sr)
```

Comment: The spatial reference isnt the problem, rather python stringhandling, se above :)